# Передача id элемента после вывода из цикла

Tags: php, javascript, mysqli

Вывожу список заданий через цикл, хочу реализовать функционал "ошибки", если задание составлено неправильно. Не могу понять как передать id  задания, в котором найдена ошибка

```
 function readonly($subject,$id)

{
    $conn = mysqli_connect($this->db_host,$this->db_name,$this->db_password,$this->db_dbname) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
    mysqli_set_charset($conn, "utf8");
    $vars = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT `tasklist` FROM `variants` WHERE `id`='$id'"));
    $vs = explode(" ",$vars['tasklist']);
    $z = 1;

    //Выводим блоки с задачами
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($vs)-1; $i++){
            $qq = $vs[$z];
            echo '<div class="taskblock"><h4>Задание №'.($z).' | ID:'.$qq.'</h4><br>';
            $line = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM `$subject` WHERE `id`='$qq'"));
             //Проверяем, изображение ли это?
        if (isset($_POST['send'])){
            $id_ = $_POST['id'];
            $subject = $_POST['subject'];


    require_once 'config.php';
    $session = mysqli_connect($this->db_host, $this->db_name, $this->db_password,$this->db_dbname);
    mysqli_select_db($session,$this->db_dbname);
    mysqli_set_charset($session, "utf8");
    $result = mysqli_query($session, "INSERT INTO reports (id_,subject) VALUES ('$id_','$subject')");    

}

                if ($line['text'] > '0' ){
                    echo ''.$line['text'].'';
                }elseif
                ($line['imgurl'] == ""){ 
                    echo 'Данного типа задания нет в базе';
                }else{
                    echo '<img src="'.'cab/'.$line['imgurl'].'"/>';
                }


                if ($line['source'] == ""){
                }else{
                    echo '</br></br><H5>Иcточник: '.$line['source'].'</H5>';
                }    

                if ($line['info'] == ""){
                    echo '</br><b>Пояснения нет</b> ';
                }else{
                echo '</br><b>Пояснение:</b></br></br> '.$line['info'].'';
                }
                if ($line['answer'] == ""){

                }else{
                echo '</br></br><b>Ответ:</b> '.$line['answer'].'';
                }
                ?>
                <br>
                <form action="cab/report.php" name="addtask" method="POST">
                //Тут планирую передавать значения id каждого задания, но понятное дело, что не получится. Будет передавать значение всех элементов сразу
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="send" value="Ошибка!"/>
                </form>
                <?php 
                echo '<hr /></div>';
                $z++;
        }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался. Передал GET-методом. Работает

```
echo '<br>'.'<a href="cab/report.php?id='.$line['id'].'&subject='.$subject.'">Ошибка!</a>';
```